# SAS: How to create variables from the values given in a specific column of a table?

Tags: sas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWSze.png

I'm using SAS and have come across a problem. I have a dataset with some variables/columns, one of which has values of only the following: blue, red, and gray. How can I convert these values into respective variables and assign the  "count" as values, as shown in the second table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add an example of your dataset. Also if you have any attempts on this show them as well. The Stackoverflow community will help you with specific questions if we can but will not do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using proc transpose. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1r2tjnp8ewe3sn1acnpnrs3xbad.htm

You could also use a data step with retain if you had a limited number of variables involved, but why reinvent the wheel?